# why is my simple SWIFT simple view black?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, label, viewcontroller

I am fairly new to SWIFT. I want to create a view from scratch. I am just trying to show a label. However, in my emulator I am just seeing a black screen. This is my SceneDelegate file:

```
import UIKit

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        
        print("start?")
        
        window = UIWindow()
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        
        let gameViewController = ViewController()
        window?.rootViewController = gameViewController
        // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
        // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
        // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
        guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    }

    func sceneDidDisconnect(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called as the scene is being released by the system.
        // This occurs shortly after the scene enters the background, or when its session is discarded.
        // Release any resources associated with this scene that can be re-created the next time the scene connects.
        // The scene may re-connect later, as its session was not neccessarily discarded (see `application:didDiscardSceneSessions` instead).
    }

    func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called when the scene has moved from an inactive state to an active state.
        // Use this method to restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) when the scene was inactive.
    }

    func sceneWillResignActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called when the scene will move from an active state to an inactive state.
        // This may occur due to temporary interruptions (ex. an incoming phone call).
    }

    func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called as the scene transitions from the background to the foreground.
        // Use this method to undo the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func sceneDidEnterBackground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called as the scene transitions from the foreground to the background.
        // Use this method to save data, release shared resources, and store enough scene-specific state information
        // to restore the scene back to its current state.
    }


}
```

This is my view controller file:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 21))
    label.center = CGPoint(x: 160, y: 284)
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
    label.text = "I'm a test label"
    self.view.addSubview(label)
    
    print("test")
}


}
```

I am seeing the debugger print:

```
start?
test
```

Any insight or tips would be greatly appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try passing scene to the window , window = UIWindow(windowScene: scene)

Answer (score 0):

The `window` should be initialized with `windowScene` as the parameter.

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    window?.rootViewController = ViewController()
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```